# Sidebar Javascript overflow error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## IMPORTANT EDIT: I MESSED UP THE DIV; ITS `#buttons`, not `#latest`. Sorry!

I have a `#buttons` div and a `latest.js` that seem to be conflicting. I tried using `overflow: auto`, `overflow: initial`, and `overflow: hidden` to fix it, and with `overflow: auto;` it seems to be doing almost what I want, except for the fact that it adds another scrollbar so that it can still stretch past the sidebar. I need for it to stay in the area of the sidebar and have it scroll down with 1 "side" scrollbar if it has to stretch past the bottom of the sidebar. I will include CSS, HTML, JavaScript, and also a `codepen` for working with it.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/TheGamingHideout/pen/KhIku)

## CSS:

```
html, body  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
body {
  background: url(http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/VexIMG/bg.png);
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666666;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'karmatic_arcaderegular';
  src: url('http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/fonts/ka1-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/fonts/ka1-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/fonts/ka1-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/fonts/ka1-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/fonts/ka1-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/fonts/ka1-webfont.svg#karmatic_arcaderegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, caption, text, font, li, ul  {
  color: white;
}
#wrap  {
  position: relative;
  width: 760px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  background: #db6d16
    url(VexIMG/header.png);
}
#navigation  {
  width: 760px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  background: red;
  padding: 0px;
}
#navigation .padding  {
  padding: 2px;
}
#navigation .navlinks  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px; left: 0px;
}
#navigation .navlinks ul  {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 760px;
  height: 35px;
}
#navigation .navlinks li {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
#navigation .navlinks li a  {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 5px 0px 9px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: karmatic_arcaderegular;
  padding: 5px 0px 9px 0px;
}
#navigation .navlinks li a:hover  {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: red;
  text-decoration: underline;  
}
#buttons  {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 113px;
  bottom: 96px;
  width: 155px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-left: 2px solid #FFA500;
  border-right: 2px solid #FFA500;
  font-family: Terminal, Arial, Times New Roman;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#700000, #250000);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#700000, #250000);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#700000, #250000);
  background: linear-gradient(#700000, #250000);
}
#latest  {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px ridge #FFA500;
  width: 297px;
  height: 195px;
}
#latest p  {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}
#static_video  {
  float: right;
  width: 295px;
  height: 200px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000, #252525, #000000);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#000000, #252525, #000000);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#000000, #252525, #000000);
  background: linear-gradient(#000000, #252525, #000000);
  clear: left;
}
#body  {
  padding-top: 60px;
  width: 600px;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Terminal;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#body a  {
  color: red;
}
#body a:hover  {
  color: lime;

}
#body .secret img  {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}   
#body .game  {
  padding: 3px 3px 10px 3px;
}
#body .game img  {
  align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 175px;
  height: 101px;
  border: 2px ridge #ff0000;
}
#body .game caption  {
  padding-left: 1px;
}
#body .space  {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 4px ridge red;
  border-bottom: 4px ridge red;
}
#body .game caption  {
  margin-top: 2px;
  float: right;
  font-family: Terminal, Arial, Verdana, San-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #e9e9e9;
}
#body .game a  {
  font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #c9c9c9;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#body .game a:hover  {
  font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer  {
  clear: both;
  width: 730px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Terminal, San-Serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #c9c9c9;
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
  padding: 13px 25px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
#footer li  {
  padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;                      
  font-size:; 10px;
}
#footer a  {
  font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #c9c9c9;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#footer a:hover  {
  font-family: Terminal, Arial, San-Serif, Tahoma;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer #footnav  {
  display: inline;
  width: 310px;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 65px;
}
```

## HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Games - TGH</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!-- This Template is a WiP - Please report any bugs to the administrative team at The Gaming Hideout. Thank you. All rights reserved. -->
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-55096101-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
    <h1><img src="VexIMG/header.png" alt="The Gaming Hideout" width="760" height="60"></h1>
    </div> 
    <div id="navigation">
    <div class="navlinks">
    <div id="output2">
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="nav.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
      <center>
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=JackSepticEye"><img src="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/VexIMG/subscribe.png"></a>
      </center>
            <br>
          </center>
        <p>
          Subscribe to the Boss, JackSepticEye's Youtube Channel!
        </p>
        <div id="latest">
          <center>
            <p id="output1"></p>
            <script src="latest.js"></script></center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
    <div class="space">
    </div>
    <!--Tons of games listed which can be viewed on the `codepen` -->
    </div>
    <div class="space">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="copyright">
    Copyright © The Gaming Hideout<br>
    We own no rights on any game on this site unless otherwise noted.<br>
    All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
    <div id="footnav">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="gamingreviews.html">The Hideout</a></li>
        <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="chat.html">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

## JAVASCRIPT (Separate files, Codepen allows one section):

```
var out = document.getElementById("output2");
var args = ["index", "application", "forum" ];

function displayMenu() {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  ul.className = "mainMenu";
  args.forEach(function (name, index) {
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
        an = document.createElement('a');
    li.className = "mmenu-item-" + index;
    li.setAttribute = "link rel", "stylesheet", "type", "text/css", "href", "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/style.css";
    an.innerHTML = name;
    an.setAttribute('href', "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/" + name + ".html");
    li.appendChild(an);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
  out.appendChild(ul);
}
displayMenu();
function showVideo(response) {
  if(response.data && response.data.items) {
    var items = response.data.items;
    if(items.length>0) {
      var item = items[0];
      var videoid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
      console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
      var video = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"; 
      $('#latestvideo').html(video);
    }
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var i;
  var document=window.document;
  var out = document.getElementById("output1");
  var args = ["Sunday, November 2nd, 2014", "We are looking for new staff members! Apply at the applications page for more information!", "There is a new MOTD under construction, so please report any bugs to the staff!"];
  function displayArgs() {
    "use strict";
    for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      out.appendChild(document.createTextNode(args[i]));
      out.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      out.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
  }
  displayArgs(args);
};

var out = document.getElementById("footnav");
var args = ["index"];

function displayMenu() {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  ul.className = "mainMenu";
  args.forEach(function(name, index) {
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
        an = document.createElement('a');
    li.className = "mmenu-item-" + index;
    li.setAttribute = "link rel", "stylesheet", "type", "text/css", "href", "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/style.css";
    an.innerHTML = name;
    an.setAttribute('href', "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/pog/" + name + ".html");
    li.appendChild(an);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
  out.appendChild(ul);
}
displayMenu();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right you just need to remove **width** from #latest div and scroll will disappear